# How to send ASCII in COM PORT in C#?

Tags: c#

I want to send ASCII command to serial Port ?
Below is ASCII command

VER < CR>< LF>(There is no space between command)

```
char[] _mass = new char[]{'V','E','R','CR','LF'};

_serialPort.Write(_mass, 0, _mass.Length);
```

How TO Create command and send it.

Comment: The SerialPort.Encoding property is already ASCII.  You need to declare your string properly, use string mass = "VER\r\n" and write it with Write(mass).  Or consider to change the NewLine property to "\r\n" so you can simply use WriteLine(mass).

Answer (score 3):

Characters in C# are UTF-16 encoded by default. When you want to communicate over the serial port, you usually use ASCII.

So you need to tell C# which encoding you want and then have it convert it to a byte array. Byte arrays are just bits without an implicit encoding.

```
byte[] _mass = Encoding.GetEncoding("ASCII").GetBytes("VER\r\n");
_serialPort.Write(_mass, 0, _mass.Length);
```